# How to install ember-collection using ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to install ember-collection on my ember-cli application...

using `ember install ember-collection` I get:

```
version: 1.13.8
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Install failed. Could not find addon with name: ember-collection
```

If I install it from bower, the component directory has just an empty file inside...

If I install it from bower specifying the repository, I get the files in my bower folder but I can't find a way to import it in my project.

I have created an `ember-collection.js` component with inside:

```
import EmberCollection from 'ember-collection/components/ember-collection';
export default EmberCollection;
```

But then I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-collection/components/ember-collection` imported from `myapp/components/ember-collection`
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember-collection is not published as npm package yet. It could be installed if github repo is specifyed:

```
ember install emberjs/ember-collection
```

After install new line should appear in package.json:

```
"ember-collection": "git://github.com/emberjs/ember-collection.git#4dbe10b7498886e277fc21b28139924f908d1926"
```

You can modify this line to provide branch or commit needed to be installed.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I have done, but then I get the error I've reported below.

Comment: I created new ember-cli app, then did the step above and try {{#ember-collection ... }} in template. It works. Import component module works too.

Comment: `Install failed. Could not find addon with name: emberjs/ember-collection`

Comment: Got it working, I had to remove every reference to ember-collection from packeges.json and then run the command to install